# Storing pairs in a GCC rope with c++11

Tags: c++11, gcc

I'm using a GCC extension `rope` to store pairs of objects in my program and am running into some C++11 related trouble.  The following compiles under C++98

```
#include <ext/rope>

typedef std::pair<int, int> std_pair;

int main()
{
   __gnu_cxx::rope<std_pair> r; 
}
```

but not with C++11 under G++ 4.8.2 or 4.8.3.

What happens is that the `uninitialised_copy_n` algorithm is pulled in from two places, the `ext/memory` and the C++11 version of the `memory` header. The `gnu_cxx` namespace is pulled in by `rope` and the `std` namespace is pulled in by `pair` and there are now two identically defined methods in scope leading to a compile error.

I assume this is a bug in a weird use case for a rarely used library but what would be the correct fix? You can't remove the function from `ext/memory` to avoid breaking existing code and it now required to be in `std`. I've worked around it using my own pair class but how should this be fixed properly?

Comment: Are you looking for a fix for your own code, or a fix that the GCC developers could implement in libstdc++?

Comment: A fix would presumably have to be in libstdc++. I can't think of this being intended behaviour. I suppose the best bet would be to fully qualify the call inside rope?

Comment: I can confirm that this still affects g++ version 6.1.1 (in case you thought that upgrading might help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If changing the libstdc++ headers is an option (and I asked in the comments whether you were looking for a way to fix it in libstdc++, or work around it in your program), then the simple solution, to me, seems to be to make sure there is only one `uninitialized_copy_n` function. `ext/memory` already includes `<memory>`, which provides `std::uninitialized_copy_n`. So instead of defining `__gnu_cxx::uninitialized_copy_n`, it can have `using std::uninitialized_copy_n;` inside the `__gnu_cxx` namespace. It can even conditionalize this on C++11 support, so that pre-C++11 code gets the custom implementation of those functions, and C++11 code gets the `std` implementation of those functions.

This way, code that attempts to use `__gnu_cxx::uninitialized_copy_n`, whether directly or through ADL, will continue to work, but there is no ambiguity between `std::uninitialized_copy_n` and `__gnu_cxx::uninitialized_copy_n`, because they are the very same function.